# Outlook 2010 broken even after uninstall and reinstall, can't even create a profile

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010

For no reason, Outlook popped up with a `data file cannot be accessed` error during send/receive. The error blocked message sending and receiving for all 4 accounts.

Summary of what I tried (nothing has worked):

- Used Microsoft's built-in Repair feature for Office 2010
- Verified PST file location in settings
- Used Microsoft PST file repair tool
- Tried to add a new data file under Mail settings, got an error `0x80070002` with no other information
- Tried to add an entirely new profile under Mail settings, got the same error `0x80070002` after putting the e-mail server info in and hitting <kbd>Next</kbd>
- Whenever I try to add a new e-mail account on the old profile, just to see what would happen, I get error `0x80070002` yet again
- Completely deleted Outlook files in the `AppData` folder
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Office 2010 Professional Plus

Reinstalling did not resolve the problem. I'm using Windows 7 64-bit, with Office 2010 Professional Plus 32-bit. Ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to use the same PST file every time? Sounds like the PST might be corrupt/damaged, too large, locked by some system process, etc.  See what happens if you use a new or different PST file, to at least isolate the source of the problem.

Comment: And a second thought just came to mind... I've seen this behavior on corporate machines where more than one version of Office was installed (because the previous version didn't correctly uninstall, usually).  Do you have more than one Office installation on your computer?

Comment: Is the system completely clean of viruses and/or malware?

Comment: Office 2010 was installed on a clean install of Win 7, so there definitely shouldn't be any other Office instances there. I can't even use a new PST file, because I get an error when I try to create a fresh Outlook profile.

Comment: I can try running MalwareBytes, but I haven't seen any evidence of malware, and I think this user knows what they're doing. I'm considering using something like Revo Uninstaller to completely wipe Outlook and try reinstalling Office. Thoughts?